# Get deactivated features with PnP

Tags: sharepoint-server, pnp-powershell, feature-activation, project-server

I am trying to automatically install and activate a solution to our Project Server 2019.

I have already installed the solution with `Install-PnPSolution`, but I cannot activate the feature.

When I activate the feature by hand, I can use `Disable-PnPFeature` to deactivate the feature again. When I do the same with `Enable-PnPFeature`, the feature does **not** get activated.

I suspect that it has got something to do with the ID of the solution. When I activate the feature by hand, I can have it listed with `Get-PnPFeature`. In this case the GUID of the feature is **not** the same as during installation.

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to get a list of **installed but deactivated** features.

How can I get a list of the **installed but deactivated** features?
What else could cause the feature not being activated?

Here the code:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credentials $cred
Install-PnPSolution -SourceFilePath $solutionPath -PackageId $solutionId
Invoke-PnPQuery
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity $solutionId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now.

There were two problems. The first was that the Solution ID and the Feature ID are not the same. The second that the sandbox flag was not set, although I am trying to install a sandboxed solution. After passing it the feature ID instead of the solution ID and setting the `Sandboxed` switch it worked like a charm.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credentials $cred
Install-PnPSolution -SourceFilePath $solutionPath -PackageId $solutionId
Invoke-PnPQuery
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity $featureId -Sandboxed
```

Unfortunately, I have not found a solution to get a list of the deactivated features remotely.

Answer (score 0):

The PnP command can  only get activated features in the SharePoint sites, you can use Get-SPFeature command.

Check the post: [Get list of all features (installed and not active) on site? Trying to use FeatureDefinitions?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61029/get-list-of-all-features-installed-and-not-active-on-site-trying-to-use-featu)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the `Get-SPFeature` is only available on the server. The script has to work remote.